The animation does not work correctly when there are few items in the list and scrolling is not allowed
In my flutter application I have a scrolling animation every time a list is updated via firebase. This animation works perfectly, but I noticed that when the elements in the list are so few that scrolling is not possible, the animation starts from above the container that should contain it. I provide the list structure code:
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final CollectionReference pensieri =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Pensieri");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF800020),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40, bottom: 15),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "Cronologia",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 240, 245, 0.75),
                      fontSize: 18,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  height: 200,
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(
                      width: 10,
                      color: const Color(0xFF9B111E),
                    ),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                  ),
                  child: ShaderMask(
                    shaderCallback: (Rect bounds) {
                      return const LinearGradient(
                        begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                        end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                        colors: [
                          Colors.black,
                          Colors.transparent,
                          Colors.transparent,
                          Colors.black,
                        ],
                        stops: [0.0, 0.05, 0.95, 1.0],
                      ).createShader(bounds);
                    },
                    blendMode: BlendMode.dstOut,
                    child: StreamBuilder(
                        stream: pensieri
                            .orderBy('time', descending: true)
                            .snapshots(),
                        builder: (context,
                            AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> streamSnapshot) {
                          if (streamSnapshot.hasData) {
                            final int docCount =
                                streamSnapshot.data!.docs.length;
                            if (docCount == 0) {
                              return const Center(
                                child: Text(
                                  "Non c'è ancora nulla qui!\nChe aspetti?",
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 240, 245, 0.75),
                                    fontSize: 18,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            }
                            return ListView.builder(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
                              itemCount: docCount,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                final DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
                                    streamSnapshot.data!.docs[index];
                                Timestamp timestamp = documentSnapshot['time'];
                                DateTime dateTime = timestamp.toDate();
                                String formattedDate =
                                    DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy - HH:mm')
                                        .format(dateTime);
                                return SlideInAnimation(
                                  key: ValueKey(documentSnapshot.id),
                                  child: Container(
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: Colors.transparent,
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                                    ),
                                    child: ListTile(
                                      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.5),
                                      title: Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                        children: [
                                          Text(
                                            documentSnapshot['id'] == 0
                                                ? "‍♀️"
                                                : "",
                                            style: const TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 30,
                                                color: Color(0xFFFFF0F5)),
                                          ),
                                          Text(
                                            formattedDate,
                                            style: const TextStyle(
                                              color: Color(0xFFFFF0F5),
                                              fontSize: 18,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                            );
                          }
                          return const Center(
                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                              color: Color(0xFF9B111E),
                            ),
                          );
                        }),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const HeartButton(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

I also provide the code of the class containing my animation:
class SlideInAnimationState extends State<SlideInAnimation>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _controller;
  late Animation<Offset> _slideAnimation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      vsync: this,
    );

    _slideAnimation = Tween<Offset>(
      begin: const Offset(0, -1),
      end: Offset.zero,
    ).animate(CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _controller,
      curve: Curves.easeInCubic,
    ));

    _controller.forward();
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(covariant SlideInAnimation oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    if (oldWidget.key != widget.key) {
      _controller.forward(from: 0.0);
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SlideTransition(
      position: _slideAnimation,
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }
}

I think the problem may be dictated by the fact that in reality the animation is always wrong, but the scroll effect hides the error; therefore, when the scroll is not performed, the error is visible.

It was enough to wrap the ShaderMask on the home page with a ClipRect. This solved my problem
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final CollectionReference pensieri =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Pensieri");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF800020),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40, bottom: 15),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "Cronologia",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 240, 245, 0.75),
                      fontSize: 18,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 425),
                  height: 200,
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(
                      width: 10,
                      color: const Color(0xFF9B111E),
                    ),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                  ),
                  child: ClipRect(
                    child: ShaderMask(
                      shaderCallback: (Rect bounds) {
                        return const LinearGradient(
                          begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                          end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                          colors: [
                            Colors.black,
                            Colors.transparent,
                            Colors.transparent,
                            Colors.black,
                          ],
                          stops: [0.0, 0.05, 0.95, 1.0],
                        ).createShader(bounds);
                      },
                      blendMode: BlendMode.dstOut,
                      child: StreamBuilder(
                          stream: pensieri
                              .orderBy('time', descending: true)
                              .snapshots(),
                          builder: (context,
                              AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> streamSnapshot) {
                            if (streamSnapshot.hasData) {
                              final int docCount =
                                  streamSnapshot.data!.docs.length;
                              if (docCount == 0) {
                                return const Center(
                                  child: Text(
                                    "Non c'è ancora nulla qui!\nChe aspetti?",
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color:
                                          Color.fromRGBO(255, 240, 245, 0.75),
                                      fontSize: 18,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                );
                              }
                              return ListView.builder(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
                                itemCount: docCount,
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  final DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
                                      streamSnapshot.data!.docs[index];
                                  Timestamp timestamp =
                                      documentSnapshot['time'];
                                  DateTime dateTime = timestamp.toDate();
                                  String formattedDate =
                                      DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy - HH:mm')
                                          .format(dateTime);
                                  return SlideInAnimation(
                                    key: ValueKey(documentSnapshot.id),
                                    child: Container(
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        color: Colors.transparent,
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                                      ),
                                      child: ListTile(
                                        contentPadding:
                                            const EdgeInsets.all(2.5),
                                        title: Row(
                                          mainAxisAlignment:
                                              MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                          children: [
                                            Text(
                                              documentSnapshot['id'] == 0
                                                  ? "‍♀️"
                                                  : "",
                                              style: const TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 30,
                                                  color: Color(0xFFFFF0F5)),
                                            ),
                                            Text(
                                              formattedDate,
                                              style: const TextStyle(
                                                color: Color(0xFFFFF0F5),
                                                fontSize: 18,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                },
                              );
                            }
                            return const Center(
                              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                color: Color(0xFF9B111E),
                              ),
                            );
                          }),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const HeartButton(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

